# Drawing a vertical rectangle instead of horizontal one and making its dimensions smaller, 3cm by 2cm

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, patterns, patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);
\draw [thick,  latex reversed-] (0,3)--(0,5)--(3,5);
\draw [thick, latex reversed-] (3,5) -- (6,5) -- (6,3);
\draw [thick, latex reversed-latex reversed] (6,3) -- (6,0) -- (3,0);
%\draw [dashed] (0,2.5) -- (6,2.5) node [above, pos=.5] {c};
\node [draw=none, anchor=east] at (0,2.5) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=west] at (6,2.5) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=east] at (0,3) {b};
\node [draw=none, anchor=west] at (6,3) {b};
\node [draw=none, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=east] at (0,5) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=west] at (6,0) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=west] at (6,5) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=south] at (3,5) {};
\node [draw=none, anchor=north] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}$$
\end{document}
```

I do not know how to draw a vertical rectangle instead of horizontal one and how to make its dimensions smaller, 3x2 cm squared? could anyone help me in implementing this please?

[image]

Comment: The coordinates represent `(x,y)` points. If you want it to be taller increase the y coordinates. Also, the `tikzpicture` should not be in math mode (ie., eliminate the two `$$`.  If you have difficulty with this, I highly recommend you delete everything except for the first `\draw` line.  Tweak those coordiantes to see how they effect the drawing.

Comment: I tried giving large numbers to $y$ and small numbers to $x$ but it did not work unfortunately, I always get a blank gab @PeterGrill

Comment: Does the following produce an image `begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, ->] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}`? If no,t you have a different problem that you need to resolve, perhaps via a separate question.  If that does indeed produce an image, try to make sense of the coordiantes by tweaking them. I included the `->` arrow so that you can see the direction of the drawing. For instance change the first `3` to `4`, and then see what changing the last `4` to `5` does.

Comment: I added the image that the code give in the question generates. Is that the result that you get?

Comment: Yeah, it is too big rectangle @P

Comment: I think I got it now @PeterGrill

Comment: Excellent. I suggest you post an answer. If you include details that will be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]